# How to calculate percentage from query?

Tags: sql

I have a query made from a select ( and receives 2 dates by parameter, i.e.@DataDe=01/01/2021 and @DataAte=18/05/2021), and i want do get all the distinct values, the total times that distinct value appears and the percentage of that value relative to all values...

My data (some values):

| Processo | data |
| --- | --- |
| Proposta | 2021-05-05 |
| Proposta | 2021-03-30 |
| Proposta | 2021-03-31 |
| Adjudicado | 2021-04-05 |
| Proposta | 2021-04-12 |
| Contacto Inicial | 2021-04-29 |
| Contacto Inicial | 2021-04-30 |
| Proposta | 2021-05-14 |
| Perdido | 2021-04-14 |

And my Query :

```
SELECT Processo, dtmInicio 
    FROM  (SELECT (SELECT strDescricao FROM dbo.Tbl_Erm_ProcessoNegocio WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (intCodProcesso = cp.intEstado)) AS Processo, cp.dtmInicio FROM            dbo.Tbl_Clientes_Potenciais AS cp WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Moedas AS Moeda WITH (NOLOCK) ON Moeda.strAbreviatura = 'EUR' LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores ON cp.intCodVendedor = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores.intCodigo LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Clientes AS cl WITH (NOLOCK) ON cp.intCodCliente = cl.intCodigo
WHERE        (cp.dtmInicio >= @DataDe) AND (cp.dtmInicio < DATEADD(day, 1, @DataAte)) AND (cp.bitConvContacto = 0) AND (cp.bitConvCliente = 0)) AS Tabela
```

From that data and query i developed this query and this output :

```
SELECT Processo, COUNT(Processo) AS Total
FROM (SELECT (SELECT strDescricao FROM dbo.Tbl_Erm_ProcessoNegocio WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE        (intCodProcesso = cp.intEstado)) AS Processo, cp.dtmInicio
FROM            dbo.Tbl_Clientes_Potenciais AS cp WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Moedas AS Moeda WITH (NOLOCK) ON Moeda.strAbreviatura = 'EUR' LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores ON cp.intCodVendedor = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores.intCodigo LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Clientes AS cl WITH (NOLOCK) ON cp.intCodCliente = cl.intCodigo
WHERE        (cp.dtmInicio >= @DataDe) AND (cp.dtmInicio < DATEADD(day, 1, @DataAte)) AND (cp.bitConvContacto = 0) AND (cp.bitConvCliente = 0)) AS Tabela
GROUP BY Processo
```

And this is output Data

| Processo | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Proposta | 5 |
| Adjudicado | 1 |
| Contacto Inicial | 2 |
| Perdido | 1 |

But i would like to add an column with the percentage of each row, relative to total.. something like this :

| Processo | Total | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Proposta | 5 | 56% |
| Adjudicado | 1 | 11% |
| Contacto Inicial | 2 | 22% |
| Perdido | 1 | 11% |

Since all data are generated according to the parameters received, and i cannot know in advance how many rows i will have, do you guys have any help or idea ?

Comment: I do know that my original query points to some tables that are not shown, but it should focus on the initial output of [Processo] && [data]... so you may consider my inicial query as a simple Select Processo,data from Tabela... and ignore the fact that that table is based on an query with an "Where" filtered by some date parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be the following ([SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aFcBWjRSVdJUv1XN4zeFcv/0) for reference):

```
WITH final AS (
SELECT 
    Processo,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_data) AS Total_Sum
FROM your_data
GROUP BY 1, 3
  )
select 
    *,  
    CONCAT(ROUND(Total / Total_Sum * 100, 2), '%') AS percentage_total
from final;
```

The subquery called `Total_Sum` will let you have an extra column with the total amount of `Processo`s, which will let you divide each group for the totality, and therefore grab the proportion :)

**OUTPUT:**

```
Processo         Total percentage_total
---------------- ----- ----------------
Proposta         5     55.56%
Adjudicado       1     11.11%
Contacto Inicial 2     22.22%
Perdido          1     11.11%
```

Comment: Thank you so much... didn't use it as my solution but made an version of that... as i said, my table gets it data with 2 parameters, and i got some problems implementing your solution so what i did was the following :

- create a View with all the raw data i needed, but without the date filter, meaning my view only got 'Processo' and 'dtmInicio', 
- applied a join between my filtered data with a count of my filtered data
- And with that i made my calculations

Comment: here is my final query: 

SELECT Main.Processo, Main.TotalParcial, Secondary.Total, CAST(CAST(Main.TotalParcial AS float) / Secondary.Total * 100 AS float) AS percentage_total FROM (SELECT Processo, COUNT(Processo) AS TotalParcial FROM dbo.USR_View_ProcessosCRMporData
WHERE (dtmInicio >= @DataDe) AND (dtmInicio <= @DataAte)
GROUP BY Processo) AS Main CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM dbo.USR_View_ProcessosCRMporData AS USR_View_ProcessosCRMporData_1
WHERE (dtmInicio >= @DataDe) AND (dtmInicio <= @DataAte)) AS Secondary